# How to center horizontally the contents of the open file in vim?

Tags: vim

how do I make vim horizontally center the text of the open file?

I don't want to modify the file, just to change the way vim displays it.

To be more clear, when I open a file I currently have this situation:

```
|<------ textwidth=80 ------->|<-------------- padding -------------->|
|lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.. 
|dsdsda da dsa dsa
```

What I'd like to have is the following:

```
|<--- padding/2 --->|<------ textwidth=80 ------->|<--- padding/2 --->|
|                    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.. 
|                    dsdsda da dsa dsa
```

Of course, for every value of `textwidth` and `padding`.

Comment: Take a look at how [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2231) does it.  IIRC it uses an empty window on either side to achieve this effect.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/folke/zen-mode.nvim

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vim isn't meant to be a single, centered document editor (when programming, you want to fill every single pixel with relevant information), so there are only workarounds:

a) You can achieve a larger left margin by expanding the fold column. Unfortunately, this is limited to 12 character cells:

```
:let &foldcolumn = (&columns - &textwidth) / 2
```

b) You can create an empty padding window to the left (and potentially also to the right, for symmetry).

```
:execute 'topleft' ((&columns - &textwidth) / 2 - 1) . 'vsplit _paddding_' | wincmd p
```

The annoying window split can be cleared with:

```
:hi VertSplit guifg=bg guibg=NONE gui=NONE
```

Comment: The second solution has also two "bonus features": you can use the left window to take quick (or disposable) notes, always at hand, and you can use your mouse to move the split a little on the left or on the right if you wish (you need `:set mouse=a` or gvim).

Comment: Is it possible to hide `_paddding_` from buffer list (and do not access it with `:bnext/bprev`)?

Comment: @paulodiovani yes, `vsplit +setlocal\ nobuflisted _padding_` should do it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could reach the point using screen.
you can open three different windows tiled vertically with

CTRL+a , SHIFT+|

then move to the second one.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all :/

Comment: wow, so there was a reason why it is not marked as the correct answer. Thank you @monokrome :D!

Answer (score 4):

Exist several plugins that allow you to get that look, most of them seem to be inspired by [Writeroom](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/writeroom) editor for MacOS.

See for example this screenshot of the the [VimRoom](https://mikewest.github.io/vimroom/) plugin, or just search the web for "vim writeroom plugin".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) for that reason. *NERDTree* is a file explorer for vim. You can load *NERDTree* at startup with any width you like:

[image]

This is how I run *NERDTree* at startup to get what you see in the image. I use [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) (a package manager for vim) to load *NERDTree*.

```sh
# Load NERDTree Plugin via vim-plug
call plug#begin()
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }
call plug#end()

let g:NERDTreeWinSize=60  # Set NERDTree width.
NERDTreeToggle            # Open NERDTree at startup.
au VimEnter * wincmd l    # Remove focus from NERDTree window at startup.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and thanks to @ingo-karkat [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953050/1712589) I managed to create a function to toggle the center content on/off.

```
function! WriteRoomToggle()
  let l:name = '_writeroom_'
  if bufwinnr(l:name) > 0
    wincmd o
  else
    let l:width = (&columns - &textwidth) / 5
    execute 'topleft' l:width . 'vsplit +setlocal\ nobuflisted' l:name | wincmd p
    execute 'botright' l:width . 'vsplit +setlocal\ nobuflisted' l:name | wincmd p
    endif
endfunction
```

Suggested options and mappings:

```
" hide vertical split separator
hi VertSplit guifg=bg guibg=NONE gui=NONE
" Do not resize windows on close (good if you also use NERDTree)
set noequalalways

" toggle writeroom on/off
map <silent><Leader>v :call WriteRoomToggle()<CR>

" delete buffer without closing the window
command! Bdelete if len(getbufinfo({'buflisted':1})) > 1 | bprev | bdelete# | else | bdelete | endif
noremap <Leader>x :Bdelete<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more approach to achieve the similar effect. You set the width of number column and in neovim you could set the width of signcolumn as well. Here is the snippet.

In vim you could utilize 'numberwidth=[n]'

```
" set your defaults as you wish
set number
set numberwidth=15
set signcolumn=yes
set relativenumber

" set the default value according to your defaults and matching flag values
" for example in here starting values match with CenterLaout 1 configuration
let s:CenterLayout=1
function! CenterLayoutToggle()
  if s:CenterLayout == 0
    let s:CenterLayout = 1

    " suitable for the long lines
    set numberwidth=15
    " if you wish to bring the LineNr color back you can reload your color scheme
    hi! LineNr guifg=bg 
  elseif s:CenterLayout == 1
    let s:CenterLayout = 2

    " suitable for no so long lines
    set numberwidth=20
    " if you wish to bring the LineNr color back you can reload your color scheme
    hi! LineNr guifg=bg
  elseif s:CenterLayout == 2
    let s:CenterLayout = 0

    " bring it back to defaults
    " suitable for long long lines
    set numberwidth=4
    " if you wish to bring the LineNr color back you can reload your color scheme
    hi! LineNr guifg=bg
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-c> :call CenterLayoutToggle()<cr>
```

In Neovim, you could do even better combining `signcolum=yes:[n]` together with `numberwidth=[n]`.

```
" set your defaults as you wish
set number
set numberwidth=15
set signcolumn=yes
set relativenumber

" set the default value according to your defaults and matching flag values
" for example in here starting values match with CenterLaout 1 configuration
let s:CenterLayout=1
function! CenterLayoutToggle()
  if s:CenterLayout == 0
    let s:CenterLayout = 1

    " suitable for the long lines
    set numberwidth=15
    set signcolumn=yes
    " if you wish to bring the LineNr color back you can reload your color scheme
    hi! LineNr guifg=bg 
  elseif s:CenterLayout == 1
    let s:CenterLayout = 2

    " suitable for no so long lines
    set numberwidth=20
    set signcolumn=yes:9
    " if you wish to bring the LineNr color back you can reload your color scheme
    hi! LineNr guifg=bg
  elseif s:CenterLayout == 2
    let s:CenterLayout = 0

    " bring it back to defaults
    " suitable for long long lines
    set numberwidth=4
    set signcolumn=yes
    " if you wish to bring the LineNr color back you can reload your color scheme
    hi! LineNr guifg=bg
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-c> :call CenterLayoutToggle()<cr>
```

In my opinion, the good side effect of `set numberwidth` and `set signcolumn` is that it would apply it to current buffer, so if you happen to work with number of source files of varying width, you could toggle it to suitable configuration for the buffer by pressing `Ctrl+C`.

If you wish to set it for all buffers then you can prefix the `set numberwidth` and `set signcolumn` with `bufdo`. The not so pleasant side effect of `bufdo` is that when you toggle the config it would take you to the last buffer. Of course you could write a work around, where you could store the reference to current buffer and after toggle come back to the referenced buffer, that would be great.

[Here is link to the gist.](https://gist.github.com/habibbhutto/110f5cd68d594da683dcdd27f11e4baa)